# I got a Solana airdrop on my terminal CLI, but SolScan shows that my balance is still 0

Tags: airdrop

I tried to airdrop SOL to my wallet and the transfer succeeded but Solscan doesn't reflect the numbers I'm seeing on the CLI.

Comment: Hey, worth checking again. I received my devnet SOL in the meantime 

Answer (score 2):

Solana has multiple networks. Airdrops are usually for devnet, testnet, or localhost.

Pick the right network in solscan (or Solana Explorer) to see the updated balance.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying, Mike. I think the problem was related to some issues in the devnet.

Tried to get SOL myself on my dev account the whole weekend but nothing happened. The Faucet on Quicknode confirmed the transfer but it did not show in my wallet balance or on solcan.

Long story short, it all seems to be working again and I see my updated balance.